# How to edit launchers in Cairo-Dock

Tags: launcher, cairo-dock, editing

I don't know how/where to find more information about the problem so I took a [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3evkCZj3FFxaTNCSjk5clVvRms) of it. If there's anything I can do to add more information to this question, I'll do it and add the information; I simply don't know how.

Comment: You can try `alacarte`.

Comment: @BlueManCZ As a command in the terminal?

Comment: As a package which you can install. `sudo apt install alacarte`.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Thank you but I still can't edit each launcher.  Like if I try to add a new, custom launcher, to launch a specific command, I can't. If I try to change the icon of a launcher, I can't because the edit screen (I assume there is one) doesn't open.

Comment: It looks like a version bug or unstable package. Do you have any previous expirience with it?

Comment: @BlueManCZ I do not. I just started using Ubuntu (from ChromeOS) a week and a half ago.